# Positioning dynamic controls dynamically in iOS ViewController

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

First of all, let me tell you that I am new in Xamarin.

I am facing a problem in rendering controls dynamically on UI.

1. Approach I am using is: Xamarin.iOS
2. I have list of Questions having different Question Types
3. I loop through all questions and render them according to the question type.
4. Client wants to have HTML in Question Title, so that he can add any type of html tags including images, links etc in HTML. (I cannot use ‘NSAttributedString’ because it doesn’t support all HTML tags)
5. I am not using AutoLayout
6. I think UIStackView is a new control which is not available for older versions

Problem is, when I render UIWebView for QuestionTitle, and other control (let us say UITextField) for simple input from user, I do not know about the exact content length of Title (which is HTML) and therefore, I set default height of UIWebView as ‘100’ and once WebView is loaded, I set the height of webview according to the content size height. While rendering control, I calculate the Y-axis for every control to be rendered. When WebView is loaded, its height gets shrunk or expanded according to the size of content and therefore, the preceding sibling’s y-axis remains there since we don’t know how much siblings are there whose y-axis should be adjusted. (Keep in mind we have multiple webviews, as we have more than 1 question).

> Is there any way, we can position all controls automatically (Just like we have LinearLayout in Android)?
>
> Is there any better approach I can follow in order to resolve this kind of blocker?

I will really appreciate your help in this problem.